# "Unable to obtain your identity" error in Git

Tags: git

I set up user.email and user.name successfully, but whenever I try to commit to a repo Git still displays an error saying that it can't recognize my identity. What could be wrong?

This is what `git config --list` command prints out:

```
user.name=myname
user.email=myemail@myemail.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
```

**Edit:** Error reads `Unable to obtain your identity: *** Please tell me who you are. Run git config --global user.email "you@example.com" git config --global user.name "Your Name" to set your account's default identity. Omit --global to set identity only in this repository. fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@computername.'(none))`

`cat ~/.gitconfig` command outputs this:

```
[user]
    name = myname
    email = myemail@myemail.com
```

`cat .git/config` outputs this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[gui]
    wmstate = normal
    geometry = 1855x1026+65+24 262 188
```

Comment: How did you set `user.name` and `user.email`? Did you use `git config` or did you edit one of the config files manually?

Comment: @Jubobs I used the git config command.

Comment: What output do you get when you run `cat ~/.gitconfig;id;cat .git/config` while you're in the repository root?

Comment: @phihag see my second edit.

Comment: @user3361043 Just to be clear, could you edit your question to add the outputs of `cat ~/.gitconfig` and `cat .git/config` separately?

Comment: @Jubobs They're there, just separated by the user ID.

Comment: @Jubobs edited again.

Comment: @user3361043 The `id` was important, but I got a glimpse. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25415432/35070) for a likely solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running git with `sudo`. In a sudo environment, `$HOME` and therefore the git configuration will not be present. Run git without `sudo`.

For the interested, here's how to reproduce the problem:

```
$ mkdir repo
$ cd repo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/phihag/repo/.git/
$ git config --global user.email "me@example.com"
$ git config --global user.name "My Name"
$ sudo git commit -m first

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@t4.(none)')
```

Notice the `root@` in the automatically detected email address.

Answer (score 7):

```
cd your project
git config --local user.name "your name"
git config --local user.email "your email"
```

I made it.

Answer (score 1):

1-open your git terminal

2-enter  **git config --list** in your git bash

3-it displays your complete git data

4- check your

user.name= your name

user.email=your email id

5- if data is not correct update it using

git config --local user.name "your username"

git config --local user.email "your email"

Answer (score 1):

Open the cmd go to your GIT repo

```
cd your project
git config --global user.email "your email registered with GIT"
git config --global user.name "your GIT user name"
```

Keep the spaces as it is. Otherwise, it will through the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. open your git bash here
2. then paste it

git config --local user.name "Your name"

git config --local user.email "your@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

if using solutions above did not fix your problem, consider using:

```bash
git config --replace-all user.email "you@domain.com"
git config --replace-all user.name "your_name"
```